# Ruby can't load JSON gem?

Tags: ruby

When I try to launch a script requiring the JSON gem, it gives me an error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /home/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXX.rb:2
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Please post the content of the script you're trying to run and the command you're using to run it.

Comment: How is this _not_ a question? Was this yet another question closed because the people involved just didn't know the answer?

Answer (score 17):

You are running Ruby 1.8+ it appears:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
```

That means your Ruby doesn't automatically load Rubygems, so you'll have to tell it what to do. Try:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
```

---

Rubygems, called `gem` at the command line, has a number of commands available to you. Try typing this at the command-line:

```
gem help
```

for a list of what it can do.

Most useful right now is:

```
gem list json
```

for a list of the gems starting with "json" or:

```
gem search json
```

for a list of the the gems with "json" in the name.

The goal is to see if the JSON gem is where its supposed to be. If it is, it will show up in the output of the command.

Another useful gem command will be:

```
gem update --system
```

which tells Rubygems to update itself. Sometimes the Rubygems application maintainers issue an update, and that command is what we do to tell it to bootstrap itself with the latest version. Because you're running an old version of Ruby, odds are really good that Rubygems is in dire need of an update. But, wait, there's more.

Because you are adjusting your system version of Ruby, you'll need to use:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

"sudo" adjusts your account to temporarily have system administration capability.

Once Rubygems has finished upgrading itself, if json didn't appear in the output from `list` or `search`, you'll need to install it using:

```
sudo gem install json
```

At that point running the `search` or `list` command should work, and, running your script with the two requires above should work.

Comment: Hi thank you. require 'rubygems' and require 'json' have been done but the problem is still there, any suggestions?

Comment: If `bundle` is used to provide execution environment, then **[this may be the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36819950/441652)** - add `gem "json"` to the `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 4):

You may not have the `JSON` gem installed. To check use the `gem list` command in the terminal, and see if you see `json`, then it's installed, if not, the do `gem install json`. Check to make sure it is in the `gem list` after the install. If it is, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you. How to check to gem list?

Comment: type `gem list` in the command terminal

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the JSON gem installed? And on that Gem path? `gem install json` should be enough

Comment: Thank you but how to do gem install json?

Comment: Open a terminal, cd into the directory where your script is. If there's a Gemfile file, type "bundle" on the terminal (if that fails, type "gem install bundler" and then run "bundle"). If there's no Gemfile, type "gem install json" and that should do it.

Comment: [xxxx@gelib-057-22 Assignment2.0]$ gem install json
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.

Comment: `sudo gem install json` then...

Comment: We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for xxxxx: -----I tried the password but it doesn't work?

Comment: Do you have a password for that user? Type it there, and if you have permissions that should do it. Otherwise, I would recommend something like bundler that will store your gems somewhere where you can actually write.

Comment: I wouldn't use the `sudo` command. I can cause problems. You should look into using RVM, which is Ruby Version Manager, from there you can use rvm gem install json.

Comment: I am the user and I tried my password but it failed every time. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'd go with @BlaineOmega's advice. Try a ruby version manager (I find RVM easier-try that one), and install gems on your home directory instead of `/usr/`.