# Running Jekyll on Mavericks with latest command line tools error

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

I'm trying to install Jekyll and keep running into issues. I'm on OSX 10.9.2, using ruby 2.1.1p76  I'm getting the following errors:

```
jekyll
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:12: uninitialized constant Gem::UserInteraction (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/ext.rb:13
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1431:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:915:in `find_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:883:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:882:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:914:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:914:in `find_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:188:in `try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/config_file.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1430:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:915:in `find_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:883:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:882:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:914:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:914:in `find_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:188:in `try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.21/lib/highline/system_extensions.rb:143
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.21/lib/highline.rb:14
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.21/lib/highline/import.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander.rb:24
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/import.rb:2
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/bin/jekyll:6
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:23
```

Does have any suggestions on things I could try in order to successfully install Jekyll?

Comment: It looks like you are using ruby 1.8 /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/

Comment: ruby --version reports /usr/local/bin/ruby. I installed this using homebrew. What should I do?

Comment: I suggest you use rbenv to manage your ruby versions. It will be a good foundation for any future ruby work.

Comment: Ok, will I need to remove rvm in order to use rbenv?

Comment: Here's a similar question that may help in troubleshooting issues with Jekyll, Ruby, and rbenv or rvm: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22277498/663607

Comment: Also note you don't *have* to use rbenv, rvm should be fine. You should be able to use a combination of `rvm list` (to show the versions available on your system), `rvm use` (to select a particular version), and `rvm default` (to keep select a system default version of ruby). There a lot of good examples on the [documentation](http://rvm.io/rvm/basics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you are trying to use ruby 2.1.1. but your log show us ruby 1.8.7.

With that in mind, it seems that you have 2 rubies installed on your machine... ruby 1.8.7 installed by homebrew, and ruby 2.1.1 installed by rvm.

And apparently you also have jekyll installed on ruby 1.8.7 gemset...

So, I recommend you to do that:

```
gem uninstall jekyll

rvm use 2.1.1

gem install jekyll
```